# Accessing all properties in array of objects for React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I'm building a search engine for Heroes of Might and Magic III and I want to check that the name of a unit entered matched the name of a unit in the data base I built. I currently have a large JSON file with an array of objects that each have a name property. Currently the code I'm working on looks like this:

```
 return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <h2>{name}</h2>

      {name === CastleUnits[0].Name && <UnitContainer data={CastleUnits} />} 
      {name === CastleUnits[1].Name && <UnitContainer data={CastleUnits} />} 


    </div>
  );
```

Where 'name' is what is passed in search and CastleUnits[0].Name works for the first unit. I've tried to solve this looping through with a for loop but I received an error.

Comment: Off topic, are you retrieving and storing data from VCMI? More curious than anything on where the data would come from. On a helpful not, if you are trying to find a single (1) match like against as a search query `const match = CastleUnits.find(c => c.Name === 'whatever')`. Other you can use `filter` `const matches = CastleUnits.find(c => c.Name.toLowerCase().includes('whatever'))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter and map through the array like this:

```
    return (
      <div className="main-content">
        <h2>{name}</h2>    
        {CastleUnits.filter(e => e.Name = name).map(e => <UnitContainer data={e} />)}
      </div>
    );
```